# Necessary and sufficient condition for a degree 4 polynomial to be a sum of 4th powers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

This is a problem I encountered in Hall and Knight's Higher Algebra. Suppose we have a polynomial $p(x,y)=a_0x^4+4a_1x^3y+6a_2x^2y^2+4a_3xy^3+a_4y^4.$
I want to find a necessary and sufficient condition on the coefficients such that $p(x,y)$ is equal to the sum of the fourth powers of 2 polynomials linear in $x$ and $y$.

I can find a necessary condition as follows:
Suppose $p(x,y)=(ax+by)^4+(cx+dy)^4$. Then, comparing coefficients,
$$a^4+c^4=a_0,$$
$$a^3b+c^3d=a_1,$$
$$a^2b^2+c^2d^2=a_2,$$
$$ab^3+cd^3=a_3,$$
$$b^4+d^4=a_4.$$

Then, doing some simple computations:
$$a_0a_2-a_1^2=a^2c^2(ad-bc)^2,$$
$$a_1a_3-a_2^2=abcd(ad-bc)^2,$$
$$a_2a_4-a_3^2=b^2d^2(ad-bc)^2.$$
Hence,
$$(a_0a_2-a_1^2)(a_2a_4-a_3^2)=(a_1a_3-a_2)^2.$$

Therefore, this condition is definitely necessary. I have a hunch that this should also be sufficient, but I don't know how to proceed with that. Are there any more conditions needed? If not, can we prove that if this condition is satisfied, one can solve for $a,b,c,d$? Any hints/suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: A) Can you clarify how $y$ comes into play? Your coefficient comparing only considers $x$, and seems to ignore $y$ completely. B) Can the fourth powers be of the form $(ax+by+e)^4$?

Comment: @CalvinLin A) My bad, I have edited the question. B) No.

Comment: Not quite what you want, but could be useful: Bruce Reznick, Some new canonical forms for polynomials, Pac. J. Math. Vol. 266 (2013), No. 1, 185–220 DOI: 10.2140/pjm.2013.266.185, https://msp.org/pjm/2013/266-1/p08.xhtml Extract from the Abstract: "a general binary quartic form can be written as the square of a quadratic form plus the fourth power of a linear form."

Comment: @GerryMyerson This was indeed quite useful! This sent me to J. J. Sylvester, “On a remarkable discovery in the theory of canonical forms and of hyperdeterminants", which solves my problem in a slightly higher generality. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Good! Let me encourage you to write up what you now know, and to post it here as an answer.

Comment: Sure, good idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The necessary condition given in the question is indeed sufficient. The following proof essentially follows from arguments in J. J. Sylvester, “On a remarkable discovery in the theory of canonical forms and of hyperdeterminants":

Using the same notation as in the question, suppose
$$p(x,y)=(ax+by)^4+(cx+dy)^4.$$

Let $b=a\lambda_1$, $d=c\lambda_2$, $s_1=\lambda_1+\lambda_2$ and $s_2=\lambda_1\lambda_2$. Then, we get the equations:
$$a^4+c^4=a_0$$
$$a^4\lambda_1+c^4\lambda_2=a_1$$
$$a^4\lambda_1^2+c^4\lambda_2^2=a_2$$
$$a^4\lambda_1^3+c^4\lambda_2^3=a_3$$
$$a^4\lambda_1^4+c^4\lambda_2^4=a_4.$$

Eliminating $a^4$ and $c^4$ from the first three equations, we get:
$$\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & a_0 \\
\lambda_1 & \lambda_2 & a_1 \\
\lambda_1^2 & \lambda_2^2 & a_2
\end{vmatrix}=0,$$
which simplifies to $a_2-a_1s_1+a_0s_2=0$.
Similarly, we can try to eliminate $a^4$ and $c^4$ from the second, third and fourth equations, as well as the last three equations. Thus, we end up with three equations linear in $s_1$ and $s_2$:
$$a_2-a_1s_1+a_0s_2=0$$
$$a_3-a_2s_1+a_1s_2=0$$
$$a_4-a_3s_1+a_2s_2=0.$$
Eliminating $s_1$ and $s_2$ from these three equations, we get:
$$\begin{vmatrix}
a_0 & a_1 & a_2 \\
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
a_2 & a_3 & a_4
\end{vmatrix}=0,$$
which is exactly the necessary condition stated in the problem.

Assuming that this condition is satisfied, we can solve the above system of equations to find $s_1$ and $s_2$. Then, solving the quadratic equation $\lambda^2-s_1\lambda+s_2=0$ allows us to find $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$. Finally, we can use the first five equations, that are linear in $a^4$ and $c^4$, to solve for them. This determines $a,b,c$ and $d$ and proves the claim.

Answer (score 0):

**Not complete answer but some observations**

- Eigenvalues

\begin{align}
  \lambda_1 \lambda_2 &= \det
  \begin{pmatrix}
    a_0 & a_1 \\
    a_1 & a_2
  \end{pmatrix} \\
  \mu_1 \mu_2 &= \det
  \begin{pmatrix}
    a_1 & a_2 \\
    a_2 & a_3
  \end{pmatrix} \\
  \nu_1 \nu_2 &= \det
  \begin{pmatrix}
    a_2 & a_3 \\
    a_3 & a_4
  \end{pmatrix} \\
\end{align}

- Necessary condition

$$\lambda_1 \lambda_2 \nu_1 \nu_2 =(\mu_1 \mu_2)^2 \iff a_2 \det
\begin{pmatrix}
  a_0 & a_1 & a_2 \\
  a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
  a_2 & a_3 & a_4
\end{pmatrix}=0$$

- (Binary) quartic form:

$$p(x,y)=
\begin{pmatrix}
  x^2 & 2xy & y^2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  a_0 & a_1 & a_2 \\
  a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
  a_2 & a_3 & a_4
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  x^2 \\ 2xy \\ y^2
\end{pmatrix}$$